# Query to display products from user in a group

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my struggle.

I have 4 tables

1:Users
2:Groups
3:Usergroupsrelation
4:Products

Users role may be Seller/Users where only Seller can add products to product table.

Super admin has ability to create Groups, where in he adds Seller or Multiple sellers to a group along with users.

Now. i need a query where in with particular userid(say user_02) i want to display products related to all sellers which user_02 belongs.

In simple words, its like whatsapp groups. Where only admins can post products in a group and all the users in groups can see the post.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use join query to fetch data

```
SELECT product_id , product_name , price FROM product
INNER JOIN users ON product.userid = users.id WHERE user.type = 1 AND user_id = 'user_02';
```

Hear you haven't provide much details so I ahve assume that in users table you have `type` field and it has `enum` value 0 = user , and 1 = seller.